Disable crons permanently in a specific Cloud Environment
It is becoming very common for my deploys to the Integration branch in Cloud to get stuck because it is impossible to kill the crons. And when I try to SSH into the server to kill them, it takes ages to connect and is super slow. I really think I can live without crons running in Integration, so I wanted to see if there was a way to disable them permanently. I usually disable them with this command:
./vendor/bin/ece-tools cron:disable

But after performing a deploy, it re-enables them. Is there a way to prevent this?

If anyone by chance is still looking for a way to attack this as it happened to me, I share that the solutions proposed above did not work for me since:

Either the crons were re-enabled when running another deploy.

They were disabled in all environments when merging from one branch to another.


The only solution that worked for me in the end was the one proposed in the following reference ticket:
https://github.com/magento/ece-tools/issues/688
I ended up adding this to my .magento.app.yaml file
# Default Magento 2 cron jobs
crons:
  cronrun:
    spec: "* * * * *"
    cmd: |
      BRANCH_REGEX="^(master|staging|production)"
      if [[ $MAGENTO_CLOUD_BRANCH =~ $BRANCH_REGEX ]]; then
         php bin/magento cron:run
      fi

This way, it runs the crons only in the master, production, and staging environments and not in the others (including integration). I don't think it's the most elegant or correct way, but it's the only one that's worked for me so far.

There are multiple ways we can disable crons ,

We can disable cron from the env.php file from app/etc/ folder. To disable add the following lines to your file
 'cron' => [
   'enabled' => 0
 ]



ref: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/files/config-reference-envphp#cron
You can commit the files changes with specific commit but generally adding or changing env is not recommanded by magento.
Also on the cloud environment, the changes made in the .magento.env.yaml file affects the app/etc/env.php generated or it overwrite them with configured deploy variable.

Other method is configuring or updating environment variables for cloud environment using  .magento.env.yaml file setting cron_run: false . 
As you have mentioned that after performing a deploy, it re-enables the cron I suggest this method with your integration environment to perform.


Ref: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-cloud-service/user-guide/configure/env/stage/variables-deploy
